# Repeating Value and Replacing Value with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, javascript-objects

Newbie in JS here. I'm having trouble replacing and repeating the value from the function.  Here's the code:

```
function Phone(ring) {
  this.ring = ring;
}
function updateRing(newRing) {  
  this.newRing = ring;
}

var samsung = new Phone('Chim');
samsung.ring(2); // Needs to compute to "Chim, Chim"

var htc = new Phone('Dada');
htc.ring(3); // Needs to compute to "Dada, Dada, Dada"
htc.updateRing('Riri');
htc.ring(1); // Needs to compute to "Riri"
```

For the repeat value for the first function, I tried using **this.repeat** but it didn't work inside the *Phone* function.

For the *updateRing* function, I couldn't get the code to replace the **this.ring**.

I stripped down all the useless code I had written.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can repeat strings with `string.repeat()`

```js
let a = "ring"

console.log(a.repeat(2))
```

But to get the comma separator to work cleanly you can make a disposable array and `join()` is with a comma.

```js
let ringString = Array(3).fill("ring").join(", ")
console.log(ringString)
```

For the others, you probably want to use classes, which are pretty easy, but don't run on IE without a ployfill. Or prototypes, which can be a little confusing at first. Here's an example using prototypes to define methods on your `Phone` object:

```js
function Phone(ring) {
  // changed to ring_tone too prevent clash with this.ring method
  this.ring_tone = ring;
}
// you need to define these on the prototype to you can use `this`
Phone.prototype.updateRing = function(newRing) {
  // don't need to define a this.newRing, just update the ring
  this.ring_tone = newRing;
}

Phone.prototype.ring = function(n) {
  return new Array(n).fill(this.ring_tone).join(', ')

}

var samsung = new Phone('Chim');
console.log(samsung.ring(2)); // Needs to compute to "Chim, Chim"

var htc = new Phone('Dada');
console.log(htc.ring(3)); // Needs to compute to "Dada, Dada, Dada"

htc.updateRing('Riri');
console.log(htc.ring(1)); // Needs to compute to "Riri"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
class Phone {
  constructor(sound) {
    this.sound = sound;
  }
  ring(number) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < number; i++) { 
      console.log(this.sound + ", ");
    }
  }
  updateRing(newSound) {
    this.sound = newSound;
  }
}

var samsung = new Phone('Chim');
samsung.ring(2);
samsung.updateRing('Riri');
samsung.ring(1);
```

Codepen - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MGRJOB?editors=0010

Comment: Would be nicer if the ring produced the desired comma-separated output (Needs to compute to "Dada, Dada, Dada").

Answer (score 0):

1) You're calling samsung.ring as a function, even though it's just an instance variable of Phone.

2) The reason why **this.repeat** didn't work is because repeat isn't a method of "this," which refers to Phone.

Try this instead:

```
var samsung = new Phone('Chim');
samsung.ring.repeat(2);

var htc = new Phone('Dada');
htc.ring.repeat(3);
```